# Intellij IDEA with perforce integration

Tags: java, version-control, intellij-idea, perforce

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13 community edition. Can some one tell me how do I integrate it with the perforce VCS. Is there such a plugin available for the latest edition.

P.S: I searched a lot and could not find a working plugin.

Comment: What OS and VCS you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Perforce VCS is only supported in the Ultimate Edition as per this link: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Check the version control section toward the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Perforce VCS integration plugin that works with the Community Editions: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7685